# Can one user's Azure OAuth to a 3rd party allow access others Office 365 calendars via proxy, with others sharing their calendar with user?

Tags: rest, azure, calendar, office365

I am trying to permit access to Office 365 calendars via Azure/OAuth2.0 via the REST API. Here is the specific scenario.

A client uses our product. It includes a scheduling feature where the client can schedule meetings based upon the Free/Busy information retrieved from others in the client’s company. Those being scheduled may not be direct users of our product.

I am able to use Azure/OAuth2.0 and Office 365 to retrieve Free/Busy information for the user logged into our product, but when this user attempts to retrieve Free/Busy information of others, a 403 Permission Denied response is returned. The others have shared their calendar with the user. I can confirm this by logging into Office 365 and see their calendars there. NOTE: This is my testing environment, so that’s why I can access Office 365.

My desire is for the client user of our product to grant access permissions for his account. Then since his Office 365 account has shared permissions with others not using our product, we would have read permissions through his proxy. We are able to do this for Google Calendars using OAuth2.0. We desire the same functionality for Office 365 and OAuth2.0 as well.

I have read answers, usually posted by Venkat, which I interpret that this feature was not available as of the fall 2014, but it will be coming soon. However, no estimated date is provided, nor have I seen updates I those specific posts that say that the feature has been delivered.

We are working on an EWS/SOAP approach in the interim.

Given that set up, here are my questions – my apologies for so many:

- Will it be possible to do what I described? That is, access to other users via one granting user via proxy?
- If so, is it available now?
- If not, any estimates on when it will be available?
- Does this require prompt=admin_consent? I don’t need all users to consent. Just the main user and then proxy access via calendar sharing on Office 365 after that.
- Speaking of prompt, used in OAuth2.0 authentication, what is the behavior when prompt is not provided?
- Is there a standard Microsoft resource I can reference for future updates? For example OAuth2.0 or Office365 API blogs and/or twitter accounts?

**[EDIT]**

@Venkat - thanks for the update. I would have commented to you directly, but I don't have the permission yet, so I've provided an edit, even if it's only a follow up question. My apologies if I'm breaking stackoverflow etiquette.

As I mentioned previously, I'm trying an EWS/SOAP approach in the interim. We have an Exchange 2010 EWS/SOAP implementation. I've confirmed it works. I substituted Office 365 URL and Domain values, but the requests return a 401 Unauthorized status. I've seen indications that Office 365 uses the same schemas as Exchange 2010, but I've also seen indications that there are differences. Can you provide any insights on how to reuse what we already have in place and what must be done differently.

One more question. Do we need to configure something on Office 365 to allow external requests via EWS/SOAP?

Comment: More narrow: I think I have a credentials problem. What Java class is needed to store login and password to an Office 365 account when creating credentials for the http request? Current implementation uses Apache's NTCredentials, which is NTLM based, and I don't think Office 365 supports NTML.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get an access denied error though the authenticating user (User A) has permissions to another user's (User B) calendar, is that the information returned in the response is based on the permissions granted to a user and permissions granted to the app.  In your example, currently, User A has sufficient permissions to see User B's calendar, but the app doesn't.  Hence, you get the 403 Permission Denied error.

We are very close (in a few weeks) to releasing support for service accounts i.e. OAuth 2.0 client credential flow.  This will enable you to build an app that, with admin consent, will be able to fetch calendar information for any user in a tenant and the easiest way to do that is [CalendarView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#GetCalendarView).  We also have plans to offer APIs similar to [EWS Free/Busy API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh532567(v=exchg.80).aspx) but I don't yet have a timeline to share with you.

**[UPDATE]:** Support for service accounts is now available.  Please see our [blog announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx) for more details and let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: Can you answer my questions above about EWS/SOAP and 401 responses?

Comment: You don't need to configure anything special to make EWS requests to Office 365.  You may need to change the way you authenticate with Office 365.  You have to use Basic authentication, and the username needs to be their UPN email address.  Office 365 doesn't support entering username as "Domain\user-alias".  Hope that helps ...

Comment: Jim, Service account support is now available.  Please take a look at the updated answer for more info.  Thanks.

Comment: EWS is working for us with most clients. But we have one for which we always receive 401; however, their credentials always pass the MFST connectivity test. I created a separate question a couple of weeks ago, but so far no comments. Can you take a quick look at: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833945/attempting-to-connect-to-exchange-domain-forest-using-ews-returns-http-401](Domain Forest EWS Returns 401)? Thanks.